# How to fetch data from a text file to a vb6 form

Tags: vb6

I have a text file in which the names of the students occur at various places. There is the text `"names"` and then the name of one student following it. Similarly, at another place this text, `"Names"` appears with the name of the student following it.

I want to fetch the name of the student one by one. That is, the first name is to be fetched and then I do some operations. Then after these operations I have to fetch another name and repeat the same operations.

How do I fetch the name of the student one by one and put them in the text box located in the `vb6` form?

Answer (score 1):

How to read a text file line by line:
http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet318.htm

Look at using InStr to find a value in the string read in.
http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/instr.html